# SMO classifier from Weka crashes on buildClassifier

Tags: java, classification, weka, text-classification

I'm trying to make an app that classifies tweet's sentiment by using [this tutorial](http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/training_a_weka_classifier_in_java.php). I wanted to compare results from Naive Bayes and SMO classifiers. While Naive Bayes works fine, SMO crashes with this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6786
    at weka.core.SparseInstance.toDoubleArray(SparseInstance.java:425)
    at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Normalize.batchFinished(Normalize.java:283)
    at weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(Filter.java:682)
    at weka.classifiers.functions.SMO.buildClassifier(SMO.java:1312)
    at machinelearning.WekaTutorial.trainClassifier(WekaTutorial.java:106)
    at machinelearning.WekaTutorial.main(WekaTutorial.java:219)
```

My app works a little bit different (it has GUI that lets you search tweets and chose which one you want to classify), but for testing purposes I modified code of the original app from the tutorial to be sure that it's not my mistake. I changed this line:

```
classifier = new NaiveBayes();
```

to this line:

```
classifier = new SMO();
```

I didn't touch anything else and I'm still getting the same error. Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Even though a year have passed, it may be relevant to others:

First of all the tutorial link provided isn't working.

Now, to me the error occurred in the following situation:

```
Instances data1 = ... // something with 50 attributes
Instances data2 = ... // something with 30 attributes
Instances data3 = new Instances(data2, data2.numInstances()) // This constructor creates an empty Instances, with the properties of data2.

data3.add(data1.isntance(0));

smo.buildClassifier(data3);
```

What we've just done is adding an instance with 50 attributes to a dataset of 30 attributes. We also trained the SMO on a dataset with 30 attributes.

Note that if you'll query data3.numAttributes() the output is 30, but if you'll query data3.instance(0).numAttributes() the output is 50.

The SMO classifier is trained on 30 attributes, and somewhere internally it queries data3.instance(0).numAttributes() which gives 50 (for me it was inside ReplaceMissingValues.class).

So I realized that the error has something to do with this difference, and I made sure that the individual instances I insert into the data3 from data1 have the correct number of attributes (e.g. data2.numAttributes()).

This solved the problem.

Comment: How did you make sure? Did you deleteAttributeAt until it was the same?